When a typical fixed output voltage LDO is unpowered, is the output pulled to ground or is it floating/high impedance?
I am wondering since in a design the gate of a PMOS is pulled up by the output of a voltage regulator.
Since the source of the PMOS still sees voltage on its source in that condition, I don't know if it will conduct or not.
I am assuming even if floating/high impedance, the parasitic losses will cause the gate to still lose its charge over time therefore the MOSFET will start conducting at some point. Correct?

There is no typical LDO. Can you be more specific if you mean some specific parts? Some may even damage if you feed voltage in through the output, and some will have a built-in output discharge feature, and most will anyway leak current through internal feedback.

TnF, There's too much abuse of the term LDO. So I don't know whether you mean it with precision, or not. But broadly speaking, any voltage regulator will have a range over which its output will be within design management and a range over which its output will not be managed (and not specified.) You can add external parts to help. But even then there will remain unmanaged ranges. It's almost impossible, without knowing details of the overall application and circuitry, to come up with something that is always in management. Circuit details matter, I suspect.
